# Complex Django query involving an ArrayField & coefficients

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

On the one hand, let's consider this Django model:

```
from django.db import models
from uuid import UUID

class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=12, max_digits=22)
    items = ArrayField(base_field=models.UUIDField(null=False, blank=False), default=list)
```

On the other hand, let's say we have this dictionary:

```
coefficients = {item1_uuid: item1_coef, item2_uuid: item2_coef, ... }
```

`Entry.value` is intended to be distributed among the `Entry.items` according to `coefficients`.

**Using Django ORM, what would be the most efficient way (in a single SQL query) to get the sum of the values of my `Entries` for a single `Item`, given the coefficients?**

For instance, for `item1` below I want to get `168.5454...`, that is to say `100 * 1 + 150 * (0.2 / (0.2 + 0.35)) + 70 * 0.2`.

| Entry ID | Value | Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | 100 | `[item1_uuid]` |
| uuid2 | 150 | `[item1_uuid, item2_uuid]` |
| uuid3 | 70 | `[item1_uuid, item2_uuid, item3_uuid]` |

```
coefficients = { item1_uuid: Decimal("0.2"), item2_uuid: Decimal("0.35"), item3_uuid: Decimal("0.45") }
```

Bonus question: how could I adapt my models for this query to run faster? I've deliberately chosen to use an `ArrayField` and decided not to use a `ManyToManyField`, was that a bad idea? How to know where I could add `db_index[es]` for this specific query?

I am using Python 3.10, Django 4.1. and Postgres 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my own question, but I'm sure someone here could come up with a more efficient & cleaner approach.

The idea here is to chain the `.alias()` methods (cf. [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias)) and the [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) with `Case` and `When` in a `for` loop.

This results in an overly complex query, which at least does work as expected:

```py
def get_value_for_item(coefficients, item):
        item_coef = coefficients.get(item.pk, Decimal(0))
        if not item_coef:
                return Decimal(0)
        several = Q(items__len__gt=1)
        queryset = (
                Entry.objects
                .filter(items__contains=[item.pk])
                .alias(total=Case(When(several, then=Value(Decimal(0)))))
        )
        for k, v in coefficients.items():
                has_k = Q(items__contains=[k])
                queryset = queryset.alias(total=Case(
                        When(several & has_k, then=Value(v) + F("total")),
                        default="total",
                )
        )
        return (
                queryset.annotate(
                        coef_applied=Case(
                                When(several, then=Value(item_coef) / F("total") * F("value")),
                                default="value",
                        )
                ).aggregate(Sum("coef_applied", default=Decimal(0)))
        )["coef_applied__sum"]
```

With the example I gave in my question and for `item1`, the output of this function is `Decimal(168.5454...)` as expected.